# Simple Python script calculates checksum from a web page

Tags: python, web-services, apache, cgi

I need a simple webservice where I can pass URL as parameter and got back the checksum of it's content as result.

So I'm looking for a simple Python script who fetches a URL from Internet and outputs SHA-2 checksum.

Does anyone have done something like this ?

Answer (score 1):

hashlib doesn't appear to have sha2, but here's sha256:

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

import sys
import hashlib
import urllib.request

def main():
    url = sys.argv[1]
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    hasher = hashlib.sha256()
    for block in response.read(2**18):
        text = response.read()
        hasher.update(text)
    print(hasher.hexdigest())

main()
```

Comment: I really like SIMPLE and straightforward solutions for SIMPLE problems. Congrats.

Comment: Hashlib's SHA256 is SHA-2 256

Comment: @dstromberg Why when I calculate the sha256sum on a file downloaded from the URL supplied, I got a different checksum. They are supposed to be identical. Why ?

Comment: It's probably a different digest algorithm.